# Mercedes B180: engine warning light is on, probably dodgy cable?

Tags: mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes B180 Diesel, from 2013/2014. The little 'engine warning light' came on, I took it to a garage, where they said it was a faulty oil pressure sensor, so they changed that. The light remained on, so now they say it is likely to be the cable; but when I asked them to change it, they weren't too keen - apparently the exhaust dust filter (forgot the proper name for it) needs regenerating, and they believe that this may be the reason this light comes on.

Does this sound likely? And why hesitate with changing the cable? Unless it is one of these things where all cables in the car are integrated in such a way that you have to change all of them, and it gets massivly expensive.

Finally, I'd like to find out for myself about this cable; is there anywhere I can findout, like a database, or does somebody here happen to know what it costs or the partnumber perhaps?

Sorry for rambling, I'm just a little fed up with this. Modern cars are too complicated - and unapproachable, not least because it seems impossible to get any real documentation.

Comment: When did you last have it properly serviced? Do you give it a long run to allow the regen to take place?

Comment: Modern cars can seem intimidating because of all the emissions and efficiency stuff, however there's now computers that manage the engines that can give us a clue to what's wrong. It would help if you added the On-Board Diagnostics (OBD) codes your car is throwing. You can often get codes read for free from auto parts stores, there are cheap readers off of the internet, or it may be written on the documentation from your mechanic.

Comment: @SolarMike It was serviced only last year. I can understand why the filter doesn't regenerate - after I started working in London, I hardle every drive far. I should probably change to electric, but this is just a very nice car in so many ways.

Comment: @GdD I do have one of these OBD readers, and I've discussed the codes with the garage; I don't recall the number, but it is definitely the oil pressure sensor or the cable - unless it is a problem with the chip, but then I think there would be more problems. I'll add the code when I have time to go and read it again.